# Chrome extension: starting options page with parameters

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My extension has four relevant parts. An injected script in a tab that gathers some data, a page action popup on that tab, a background script that mediates data between the two, and an options page. The popup has a button which opens the options page.

*I would like to open the options page from the popup and give it some data, so that it could show options relevant to that tab.* Below is my stripped down and edited attempt at solving this:

**popup.js**

```
var popup = (function() {

    var tabId;

    function openOptions() {
        port.postMessage({
            action: 'openOptions',
            id: tabId
        });
    }

    function connectToBackground(tabs) {
        if (tabs.length > 0) {
            tabId = tabs[0].id;
            port = chrome.runtime.connect();
            port.postMessage({
                action: 'connect',
                id: tabId
            });
        }
    }

    return {
        initialize: function() {
            document.getElementById('settings').addEventListener('click', openOptions);
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, connectToBackground);
        }
    };
})();
popup.initialize();
```

**background.js**

```
var background = (function() {
    var tabs = {};
    return {
        onConnectInjected: function(port) {
            chrome.pageAction.show(port.sender.tab.id);

            port.onMessage.addListener(function(message, port) {
                if (message.action === 'connect') {
                    if (!tabs[port.sender.tab.id]) {
                        tabs[port.sender.tab.id] = {};
                    }
                    tabs[port.sender.tab.id].injected = port;
                    tabs[port.sender.tab.id].tabData = message.data;
                }
            });
            port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
                tabs[port.sender.tab.id].injected = null;
            });
        },
        onConnectPopup: function(port) {
            port.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
                if (message.action === 'openOptions') {
                    chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage(function() {
                        for (let view of chrome.extension.getViews()) {
                            if (view.options) {
                                view.options.showOptionsRelevantToTab(tabs[message.id].tabData);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else if (message.action === 'connect') {
                    if (!tabs[message.id]) {
                        tabs[message.id] = {};
                    }
                    tabs[message.id].popup = port;
                    port.onDisconnect.addListener(function(port) {
                        tabs[message.id].popup = null;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
})();
chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener(background.onConnectInjected);
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(background.onConnectPopup);
```

**options.js**

```
var options = (function() {

    return {
        showDefaultOptions: function() {

        },
        showOptionsRelevantToTab: function(data) {

        }
    };
})();
options.showDefaultOptions();
```

The magic is supposed to happen in background.js in the callback to `chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage`. From what I gather, this callback is called when the options page has successfully opened, yet `chrome.extension.getViews()` only returns the background view (and oddly enough the popup view).

I've tried opening the options page directly from the popup, but since the options are opened in another tab, the popup loses focus and closes so the callback never fires. I've also explored sending a message from the options page to the background script, but then background.js has no sure way of knowing which tab spawned the options page.

I've also tested calling getViews in options.js and it actually returns the popup (which in turn could provide the data) but I can't be sure that this is consistent, given that the popup exits at the same moment.

So again, how can background.js get the options page's window object on creation, so that it can give it the relevant data, or alternatively - let settings.js know which tab created it so that it can grab the relevant data from background.js. I'd prefer if I didn't have to add the 'tabs' permission just for this.

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to have the options page make a call to the background page to get the relevant page data. It would look something like this:

```
// options.js init code:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "getOptionsData"}, (response) => {
  // Now that you have the response, you can set your settings and then make the page visible
});
```

In your background.js you would need to handle this. The easiest way would be to save a global variable `optionsState` that you would set in your `openOptions` handler, and then return that data inside of `getOptionsData`

This shouldn't be an issue because multiple tabs shouldn't be opening options in your example.

e.g.

```
// at the top of background.js
let optionsData = null;

// inside openOptions, before calling openOptionsPage,
optionsData = tabs[message.id].tabData;

// inside getOptionsData (make sure to expose sendResponse as a function param
return sendResponse(optionsData);
```

Comment: This could definitely work. I would have to make it "read-once" so that it is null the next time options opens by right-clicking the page action in another tab, so that the default options are displayed instead.

Comment: I got it to work, sort of. Open the options from a popup and it displays relevant data. However, if you leave options open, the next call from another tab will just switch focus to the options page with the old data.

Comment: Fixed the above issue with a listener to the 'focus' event on the options page window.

Comment: @electricmanamonkey the focus event also happens when the user clicks the tab again with the options page. The options page can also be opened from the context menu on the top right.  How do you know if the user is simply clicking on the option tab and calling if from the context menu?